# Attribute Error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'

Tags: qgis-2, python-2.7

I am developing a plugin that counts the number of features for a layer in QGIS 2.6. The plugin works fine when there is a layer but when there is no layer, it throws an error. For reference, a part of the code is also attached.

```
def run(self):
    """Run method that performs all the real work"""
    # show the dialog
    self.dlg.show()

    layers = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values()
    for layer in layers:
        if layer.type() == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer:
            self.dlg.featurecombo.addItem( layer.name(), layer )
    # Run the dialog event loop
    result = self.dlg.exec_()
    # See if OK was pressed
    if result  == 1:
        index = self.dlg.featurecombo.currentIndex()
        layer = self.dlg.featurecombo.itemData(index)
        if layer > 0:
            QMessageBox.information(self.iface.mainWindow(), "feature count","%s has %d features." %(layer.name(), layer.featureCount()))
```

[image]

Comment: Your code is indicating that "name" does not exist in the object you are looping through. Try: import pprint and then in your loop: pprint.pprint(layer). This should help verify that "name" exists. Does it?

Comment: I made a change in the looping when there is no layer. That works. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is indicating that "name" does not exist in the object you are looping through. Try: `import pprint` and then in your loop: `pprint.pprint(layer)`.

If layer does not exist, then you will know what is causing your error and what items in your object are available for parsing.

Stay curious my friend.

Comment: Yeah edited the code and now it works fine.Thanks.